# Localization in Blackberry Resource interface not generating

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to implement localization in Blackberry for multiple language support.
For this I followed the tutorial from the following link

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Localizing-an-application/ta-p/442726

but i got the issue as described in this link

[BlackBerry: Localization, Resource Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568079/blackberry-localization-resource-bundle)

But for me the file is still not generating even when I had created my .rrh file , i am following the same steps but still no success .

can anyone tell what I m missing ??

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have cleaned your project and checked "build automaticaly".
Then check your bin folder to the specified package in the option of the resource editor for the generated interface